# Pronunciation: ah, oh, etc

Tags: pronunciation, ipa, pronunciation-respelling

English vowels have several pronunciations so when people try to explain how to pronounce foreign words (without IPA, which is what they should be using ;-)) they add lots of silent Hs and hyphens, e.g. KAH-zah.

Problem is, as a non-native speaker this only adds to the confusion. What's the meaning of those Hs at the end of syllables? Do they make the vowels short or long? In "uh-oh", they seem to do both (it sounds as /oʔoʊ/ to me).

Could someone use IPA to explain how **"ah, eh, ih, oh, uh"** sound and tell me how they differ from **"a, e, i, o, u"** that make people feel the need to add an H?

Comment: Generally they're short, except for "ah" = "f**a**ther" and "oh" = "toe". Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37358/why-is-oh-spelled-oh-and-not-o

Comment: In English, the vowel sounds depend heavily on the context, and the _H_ helps us set that context.

Comment: @sumelic Thanks, that's what I needed to know. I had found that question before (that's why I used uh-oh as an example), but I wanted to expand on it (especially because oh seems to be the exception among the vowels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English does not have a phonemic orthography, so there are numerous pronunciation respelling systems to express what words sound like. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English) lists a lot of them. Of those listed, only one (World Book Online) uses these five (IPA equivalent(s) in parenthesis):

- ah (ɑː)
- eh (ɛ)
- ih (ɪ)
- oh (oʊ)
- uh (ʌ, ə, ɨ)

Also, hyphens are used to separate syllables and CAPS represent stressed syllables.

---

It's worth noting that I was not taught to use any one of these systems in school (US). For this reason, it seems likely a lot of people aren't going to be using a standard system, especially if they're random people on the internet. IPA in particular is impossible to use without learning first, and can't be typed on any standard keyboard.

Comment: Oh, I forgot I had asked about a, e, i, o, u too. I guess they (are supposed to) sound like their names, is that right? Or maybe they rest unused because they are deemed too ambiguous?

Comment: WBO seems to use them for æ, (nothing), (nothing), ɒ/ɑ, ʊ/ᴜ if I'm reading the table correctly.