# Writing Time at the Beginning of a Sentence

Tags: time

I'm a court reporter and can't move words around.   Writing out "Three o'clock" at the beginning of a sentence is a given.    What to do when the time is 3:01?   And the zero creates an additional question.

Q.  What time did you get to the store?

A.  3:01.

A.  Three oh one.

Preemptive strike:

A.  Three zero one.  (Can't do this.  It's not verbatim.)

A general rule would be appreciated.  My reference book has the easy answers, but this rule is not addressed.  Couldn't find anything online.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "oh" spelled "oh" and not "o"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37358/why-is-oh-spelled-oh-and-not-o) That's mostly about "invocatory **Oh**", but [one of the answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/492236/2637) addresses the two different possible spellings for the vocalised version of the ***digit***. In the final analysis this is a matter for your chosen (or imposed) style guide.

Comment: The problem is that the technology is obsolete. Visual and audio recording is required for accuracy; any transcription is a translation from language to writing, not a true record.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Is it fair to say that most if not all future *readers* of any such transcription would normally "translate" back to the original audio? At least by listening to that "voice in one's head", if not actually *vocalising* it. I seem to remember something about the first person ever observed to be reading without moving his lips, which may be relevant here. I find it hard to imagine understanding written text without in *some* fashion "hearing" it. I personally don't normally "vocalise externally", but I certainly do it sometimes with complex texts, even if I'm completely alone.

Comment: If you haven't an example in a style guide, or previous example, to rely on, isn't there something about precedents being important in law? Three-oh-one, Three-o-one, Three oh one and Three o one seem reasonable candidates. I'd say 'oh' looks better than 'o', and the hyphens make the composite (single time) clearer.

Comment: If the witness said "three oh one" that is what you should write. If later the witness was reminded that he arrived at 3 o'clock he might say "No I didn't, I said the street number of the shop" and your record will be in conflict.

Comment: Mr. Lawler, imagine having to review a six-week trial for appellate purposes by reading the transcripts versus (ah-ha) watching a videorecording or listening to an audio recording.   Court reporters produce accurate records.  Judges' rulings and attorneys' actions are guided by them.  I'm interested to know what technology you think is outdated.

Comment: Mr. Edwin and Ms./Mr. Vane, thank you for your input and actually attempting to answer the question I asked.

Comment: "3:01" is easier to read and is an accurate way to transcribe "three oh one" In response to a question about time, - there is no other reasonable way to interpret "three oh one" in that context, and also if reading aloud from a transcript that says "3:01" most people would say "three oh one". Having said that, you have a very specialised need here, I think you really need to confirm with the court what they expect you to do.

Comment: @Michael Harvey  Yes; I was saying that you provide (now provided) a corroborating reference. And for once, I think the image of the original was justified. Where'd it go?

Comment: Take the opportunity to ask a lawyer or judge your question. Anything you read here will be from people whose area of expertise is the English language. (As I - legal experience - see it, 3:01pm is fine. A time is being stated, it does not matter how it is written, the meaning will be univocal.)

Comment: Just give the time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing what the witness said, then the witness said "Three-oh-one" and that is what you should write.

There is no possible confusion. The question, "What time ..."  makes the context clear.